# visual studio code bugs

Tags: python

I have visual studio code on my mac, and it do strange bugs.
This code should end my while loop if I type quit, but instead it loop infinite with asking "Say something: "

```
results = []

while True:
    user_input = input('Say something: ')
    if user_input == "quit":
        break
    else:
        results.append(sentence(user_input))
```

And this code should open a file located in the same directory as the .py file, but instead I got error that the file doesn't exist

```
myfile = open("fruits.txt")
print(myfile.read())
```

The output:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fruits.txt'

I have delete completely VSCode from my mac and reinstall it. Same problem.
In Jupyter notebook work without problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced the case, but there is no problem.

But I guess your .py file and .txt file should be located in a same directory in the workspace.

The pylance identification file is based on the location of workspace instead of the floder of the current file. You can use absolute paths.

For example:

```
myfile = open("C:/my_python/test/fruits.txt")
print(myfile.read())
```

**Edit:**

For the first problem, you can try debugging. I think there is something wrong with your code. I still haven't encountered the situation you said.

Comment: I don't know what was the problem, I have deleted again vscode, all my docs folders with .py files, I have created from 0, and it works, maybe with the workspace problem, but still don't understand why, cause now, it looks exaclty like previous version

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
user_input = input('Say something: ')
user_input == 'quit'
```

separately.

The second problem: What is your working directory?

```
import os
os.getcwd() # get current working directory
```

Your 'fruits.txt' should be in that working directory, otherwise python cannot find it.

instead of relative path, do:

```
with open("~/insert/here/absolute/path/to/fruits.txt") as myfile:
    print(myfile.read())
```

In windows, your absolute path would look like: "C:\your\to\fruits.txt".

Comment: What do you mean try separately?
Second problem: as I explain, the project is in the same workspace(new created) same directory. you just repeat my questions.